# Delete object managed by two shared_pointer instances when either is deleted

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a directed graph model represented by `Node` and `Edge` classes. Each `Node` object holds pointers to all its outgoing AND incoming edges and each `Edge` object holds pointers to its origin and end (`Node` objects).

```
class Model
{
public:
    ~Model() 
    {
        for(Node *node : nodes)
            delete node;
    }

    QVector<Node*> nodes;
};

class Node
{
    public:
    ~Node
    {
            for(Edge *edge : from)
            {
                if(edge)
                {
                    edge->to->to.replace(edge, nullptr);      
                    delete edge;
                }
            }

            for(Edge *edge : to)
            {
                if(edge)
                {
                    edge->from->from.replace(edge, nullptr);
                    delete edge;
                }
            }
    }

    QVector<Edge*> from;
    QVector<Edge*> to;
};

class Edge
{
public:
    Node *from;
    Node *to;
};
```

So far I have it implemented using raw pointers like this. It is rather complicated and involves manually removing the pointer from the other side of the edge (for every edge) when the node is deleted.I would rather like using smart pointers to make it all a bit safer and cleaner.

However the fact that I need to delete the edge (and invalidate the pointer on the other side) for both sides makes it problematic. If I used shared pointers the edges would never get deleted (and the remaining reference would remain valid even when the other side is gone). If I used weak pointers I would in turn need to store the shared pointer somewhere else which would again become more complicated because I would need to look it up and get rid of it whenever either side gets deleted.

What I need is a "smart" pointer that will keep track of the pointee (like shared pointer) but delete its pointee when its internal counter drops to 1 (instead of 0) so that it invalidates itself (like weak pointer) without going out of scope.

Should I write it myself or is there another solution?

Comment: Conceptually it looks like that works. You are saying you would rather do it differently? What would doing it differently solve?

Comment: @JClark4321 Two issues actually. One is the fact that when deleting all nodes I needlessly replace all edge pointers with nullptr which is a slow operation (linear time) whereas with automatic pointers I would no need to do that. The second issue more general but there is a awful lot of advice suggesting against ever using raw pointers (coming from Bjarne himself for example) so I wanted to comply with this as well as I can never know for sure my design is bulletproof (or rather - memory leak proof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nodes**

Every edge is referred to by at least two nodes. If no node refers to an edge, this edge is useless and can be deleted. This suggest that the pointers from node to edge should be `shared_ptr<Edge>`.

The pointer vector in Model should by the way be `shared_ptr<Node>`

**Edges**

The edge can exist only if the source and destination nodes exist, but nodes can exist without edges. This suggest that the pointer in edges to nodes should be `weak_ptr<Node> from, to`;

You can always check if `from` or `to` nodes were deleted with [`from.expired()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired).  But you have no way round the proper way to remove the edge:  removing its pointer from both sides, in which case, the destruction of the edge is triggered when no longer needed.

Comment: Well you gave me an idea there. Currently before I use the edge I obtain from a node I validate it checking if it is not in fact nullptr (as would be the case if the other side deleted it like in OP). Witht your suggestion I would not actually delete the edges from either side but instead of checking the validity of the edge pointer I would check whether the edge is invalid (either node it points to expired). It is a three function calls extra (edge->isValid() that in turn calls from.expired(), to.expired()) but I think it is worth it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to be able to do is invalidate all pointers to a `Node` instance if that instance is deleted. This implies you want a notion of self-ownership. Thus, all pointers to the `Node` should be weak pointers to a shared pointer managed by `Model` (or perhaps the `Node` itself).

Each `Node` can be made to only have weak pointers to neighboring nodes. An `Edge` can be made on demand as needed, and an `Edge` would also only consist of weak pointers.